# How to remove empty space of widget removed?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have a code that works fine but there is a problem. After user click on icon 'delete', widget is removing and there is empty space after that widget.
How can I remove empty space? I realy cannot anderstand how to fix it.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

KV = '''
<RVItem>
    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: 'delete'
        del_id: root.del_id
        on_release: app.delete(self)

Screen:
    rv: rv
    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'RVItem'
        do_scroll_x: False
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            size: self.minimum_size
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None

'''

class RVItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    del_id = StringProperty()

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.rv.data = [{'text': str(x), 'del_id': str(x)} for x in range(10)]
    
    def delete(self, instance):
        for item in self.root.children[0].children[0].children:
            if item.text == instance.del_id:
                self.root.children[0].children[0].remove_widget(item)

MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RecycleView` is based on its `data`, so removing one of its child widgets will actually have no effect beyond the temporary disappearance of that one widget (it will reappear when you scroll). To actually remove an item from a `RecycleView`, you must remove it from the `data` Try modifying your `delete()` method to do this:

```
def delete(self, instance):
    for item in self.root.rv.data:
        if item['del_id'] == instance.del_id:
            self.root.rv.data.remove(item)
            return
```